# Was the Crab Nebula to the southeast of Zeta Tauri 1,000 years ago?

Tags: observational-astronomy, supernova, history, precession

I've been reading about [SN 1054](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN_1054) and how most professional investigators believe that it is the Crab Nebula today. But the wiki article has this to say:

> The location of the guest star as "to the south-east of Tianguan, perhaps several inches away" has perplexed modern astronomers, because the Crab Nebula is not situated in the south-east, but to the north-west of Zeta Tauri.

Well, then I remembered the [precession of the equinoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession). I know precession does not change the fixed background of stars, but can change their relative location.

If we rewind the precession 1000 years, **does Zeta Tauri cross the zero meridian or the celestial equator?**

Comment: Precession wouldn't change the relative position of stars/nebulae to each other. The Crab Nebula is essentially a "fixed star" in this respect. Possibilities: report is inaccurate, proper motion of either object.